# How to add an html into the body text of chrome extension's notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension and now I want to add an image on the body text on a notification.

Here is my code for notification:

```
var opt = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "title",
  message: "Please wait while we take you to our site...",//There I want the image
  iconUrl: "48.png"
}

chrome.notifications.create('id', opt, function(){});
```

Comment: What kind of notification are you talking about? In any case, this is probably impossible, but do add the code you're using for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Chrome notification system is quite rigid. You can't directly access the HTML of the notification, and you're limited to the [options provided](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions).

So, a `"basic"` type notification will only have an icon and some text.

There is, however, an `"image"` type notification:

[image: Image notification]

It has the same format as a normal notification, plus an extra image provided by the `imageUrl` parameter. This may or may not help you.